# How get current layout name?

Tags: metadata, page-layout

If I know layout name I can read what layout contains using following Metadata. At the same time if somebody changes Layout name this code won't work at all. Could you please advise if I can get the name of layout currently assigned to user for the object?

```
List<Metadata.Metadata> mm= Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout , new List<String> {'Account-Account Preview Layout'});
        ILayoutI = (Metadata.Layout) mm.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue,I used Named Credential to resolve this issue.
To create Named Credentials i used this link,
https://rajvakati.com/2018/01/28/salesforce-ui-api-lightning-examples/

used this link,
[Getting Page Layout associated to a Profile/RecordType](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32683/getting-page-layout-associated-to-a-profile-recordtype)

to set tooling API,the change which i made was ,i replaced

'/services/data/v41.0/tooling/query?q='+ (query.replace(' ', '+')) in following method

```
static String toolingAPISOQL( String query) {
String baseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
return restGet( baseURL +'/services/data/v41.0/tooling/query?q='+ (query.replace(' ', '+')),'GET', UserInfo.getSessionId() );}
```

with

```
static String toolingAPISOQL( String query) {
    String baseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
    return restGet('callout:PageLayout/services/data/v41.0/tooling/query?q='+ (query.replace(' ', '+'))
                   ,
                   'GET');
}
```

in this callout is fixed name used for named credential and PageLayout is the name of the named credential which i created